# Why am I getting Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)' on VBA code for exporting to pdf that worked fine on older Excel versions?

Tags: excel, vba

Moving from Excel 2007 to 2016 I am trying to use a simple VBA code exporting a sheet to pdf file. Worked well in the previous version of Excel but now I am getting -2147417848 (80010108) Automation Error: The Object invoked has disconnected from its clients. This is my code:

```
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="C:\Users\jiric\xxx.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

I have tried to record a macro in this Excel 2016 (just to "save as" / or "export to pdf") and I got this code (seems cracked to me, even debugger says "compile error" obviously):

```
    . Item := xlTypePDF,  :="C:\Users\jiric\xxx.pdf",  :=xlQualityStandard,  := TRUE,  := FALSE,  := TRUE
```

Is there something wrong with Excel 2016?? :) I am getting this run-time automation error on two different computers, but both with the same excel version (same installation). Any ideas to fix this? Other parts of VBA code work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i encountered the same issue...............with windows 10 professional and office 2016 Pro Plus. I have no problem with the same kind of code